# React: Get state of children component component in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I have this container where  and  is not placed in the same level. How can I get the state of the Form when I click on the button (which is placed on the parent) ?

I've created a demo to address my issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kmqw47p8x7

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  save = () => {
    alert("how to get state of Form?");
    //fire api call
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form />
        <button onClick={this.save}>save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

- One thing I don't want to do is sync the state for onChange event, because within Form there might be another Form.

Comment: Move button to Form and pass state onclick to parent

Comment: @Justcode I want to but it's not as straight forward as that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access a child instance from parent, your need to know about [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

First, add `formRef` at top your App class:

```
formRef = React.createRef();
```

Then in App render, pass `ref` prop to your Form tag:

```
<Form ref={this.formRef} />
```

Finaly, get state from child form:

```
save = () => {
    alert("how to get state of Form?");

    const form = this.formRef.current;
    console.log(form.state)
};
```

Checkout demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/38oq3915l6)

Comment: this works but you should not use this. it breaks component encapsulation. 
react docs says dont overuse refs, it should only be used to access dom node refs.

Comment: yes, I agree about don't overuse refs. But in this case, to keep the structure of the component tree, using ref is best approach.

Comment: This is so cool, listening to form state is not ideal because the form state itself has dropdown, bunch of user interactive stuff or possible child form, this ref approach just make my code much more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

ideally, your form submit action belongs to the `Form` component
You can put `button` inside your `From` component and pass a submit callback to the form.

```
  class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

   save = (data) => {
     // data is passed by Form component
    alert("how to get state of Form?");
    //fire api call
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onFormSubmit={this.save} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the structure

Answer (score 0):

you can write the code like this

https://codesandbox.io/s/23o469kyx0

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned, a ref can be used to get stateful component instance and access the state, but this breaks encapsulation:

```
<Form ref={this.formRef}/>
```

A more preferable way is to refactor `Form` to handle this case, i.e. accept `onChange` callback prop that would be triggered on form state changes:

```
<Form onChange={this.onFormChange}/>
```

> One thing I don't want to do is sync the state for onChange event, because within Form there might be another Form.

Forms will need to handle this any way; it would be impossible to reach nested form with a ref from a grandparent. This could be the case for [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

E.g. in parent component:

```
  state = {
    formState: {}
  };

  onFormChange = (formState) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      formState: { ...state.formState, ...formState }
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form state={this.state.formState} onChange={this.onFormChange} />
    );
  }
```

In form component:

```
  handleChange = e =>
    this.props.onChange({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

  render() {
    return (
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="firstName"
          value={this.props.state.firstName}
        />
    );
  }
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5nxxvx3zk).

Comment: lifting up the state should be the 'normal' way, but my concern is form within form. I have multiple binding on my form and children form, meaning when the children from state changed, I have to lift the states to multiple parents, the code looks really ugly.

Comment: *the code looks really ugly* - that's a good reason to use state management library. Can you update the question with code for your form within form? Again, you can't reach nested form with a ref. Refs are often antipatterns, they are certainly antipatterns in this case.

Comment: so should I do this? `componentDidUpdate() {this.props.getChildState(this.state)}` in the form?

Comment: This wouldn't be lifted state. Lifted state means that nested components don't need their own `this.state`; there's one source of truth and it's located in parent component. I updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: the demo link is wrong, I think you forgot to fork. Well you put every states in parent, what if the form has dymanic rows and complicated user interaction like drag and drop? then your container will be over populated.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I forgot to save it after forking. The container needs to hold the state but doesn't need to hold the logic to manipulate it. Interactions can stay in child components, they just need to return updated state to the parent. That's how unidirectional data flow works.